# AWS EKS Cluster , DockerHub and Traefik, not accessible from internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, traefik, amazon-eks

`kubectl get nodes`

```sh
NAME                              STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-192-168-119-55.ec2.internal    Ready    <none>   29h   v1.16.12-eks-904af05
ip-192-168-156-180.ec2.internal   Ready    <none>   29h   v1.16.12-eks-904af05
ip-192-168-193-177.ec2.internal   Ready    <none>   29h   v1.16.12-eks-904af05
```

```sh
kubectl get svc

NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
hostname-v2   ClusterIP   10.100.163.163   <none>        80/TCP    29h
kubernetes    ClusterIP   10.100.0.1       <none>        443/TCP   36h
my-app        ClusterIP   10.100.147.193   <none>        80/TCP    9m48s
```

```sh
kubectl get svc -n kube-system

NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                              PORT(S)                       AGE
kube-dns                  ClusterIP      10.100.0.10      <none>                                                                   53/UDP,53/TCP                 25h
traefik-ingress-service   LoadBalancer   10.100.113.186   a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80:30015/TCP,8080:31515/TCP   88m
```

- `kubectl describe pod my-app-898f57d6f-dsfg6`

```sh
Name:         my-app-898f57d6f-dsfg6
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         ip-192-168-119-55.ec2.internal/192.168.119.55
Start Time:   Sun, 12 Jul 2020 16:53:53 -0400
Labels:       app=my-app
              pod-template-hash=898f57d6f
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/psp: eks.privileged
Status:       Running
IP:           192.168.79.54
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.79.54
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/my-app-898f57d6f
Containers:
  simple-node:
    Container ID:   docker://cd6c686fe8f5460d5985a81a8d75da9c76371e26572b5144d5d43b55a0415ddd
    Image:          pythonss/ex1-node-app
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://pythonss/ex1-node-app@sha256:1ad843251ce45c21df4be52a34565217ea7cc441f2961d90c8e466af14473003
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Sun, 12 Jul 2020 16:53:54 -0400
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-jm5s2 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-jm5s2:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-jm5s2
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:          <none>
```

```
kubectl --namespace=kube-system get pods
NAME                                         READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
aws-node-j76qj                               1/1     Running   0          19h
aws-node-sqrqq                               1/1     Running   0          19h
aws-node-ws9kv                               1/1     Running   0          19h
coredns-55c5fcd78f-2jvzg                     1/1     Running   0          25h
coredns-55c5fcd78f-dlftl                     1/1     Running   0          25h
kube-proxy-g9pbv                             1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-proxy-wzfpc                             1/1     Running   0          19h
kube-proxy-znptc                             1/1     Running   0          19h
traefik-ingress-controller-5bdbcfc59-87rd8   1/1     Running   0          88m
```

I also applied the traefik manifest and at the same time  changed the LB type from NodePort to LoadBalancer

```sh
kubectl apply -f <(curl -so - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/v1.7/examples/k8s/traefik-deployment.yaml | sed -e 's/NodePort/LoadBalancer/')
```

```
kubectl get svc -n kube-system

NAME                      TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP                                                              PORT(S)                       AGE
kube-dns                  ClusterIP      10.100.0.10      <none>                                                                   53/UDP,53/TCP                 2d20h

traefik-ingress-service   LoadBalancer   10.100.113.186   a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com   80:30015/TCP,8080:31515/TCP   44h
```

```
host a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 107.22.153.204
a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 52.44.97.64
a262f21c7a0c740949c3321ab77a0259-639235071.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com has address 34.195.130.205
```

I applied a hostname manifest so I could later do

curl 34.195.130.205 hostname-v1.local

as under

hostname-ingress.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hostname-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostname-v1.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: web
```

```sh
kubectl create -f hostname-ingress.yaml
# OUTPUT
ingress.extensions/hostname-ingress created
```

Take INGRESS_ADDR and associate it with the domain name in /etc/hosts

```sh
echo "$INGRESS_ADDR hostname-v1.local" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
# OUTPUT
34.195.130.205 hostname-v1.local
```

```sh
kubectl create -f hostname-ingress.yaml
# OUTPUT
ingress.extensions/hostname-ingress created
```

```
kubectl get ep
NAME          ENDPOINTS                               AGE
hostname-v2   <none>                                  20h
kubernetes    192.168.219.41:443,192.168.94.137:443   27h
my-app        <none>                                  19h
```

Now let's take our INGRESS_ADDR and associate it with the hosts in etc/hosts

```sh
echo "$INGRESS_ADDR hostname-v1.local" | sudo tee -a /etc/hosts
# OUTPUT
34.195.130.205 hostname-v1.local
```

Here is also service.yaml and deployment.yaml

service.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    run: my-app
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    run: my-app
```

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  labels:
    app: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: simple-node
        image: pythonss/ex1-node-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

```sh
 kubectl get pods --show-labels |egrep 'app=my-app'                                                                 
my-app-898f57d6f-dsfg6   1/1     Running   0          128m   app=my-app,pod-template-hash=898f57d6f
my-app-898f57d6f-hchhb   1/1     Running   0          128m   app=my-app,pod-template-hash=898f57d6f
my-app-898f57d6f-hh4cw   1/1     Running   0          128m   app=my-app,pod-template-hash=898f57d6f
```

And

```sh
kubectl describe svc my-app   
                                                                                  
Name:              my-app
Namespace:         default
Labels:            app=my-app
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app=my-app
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.100.147.193
Port:              <unset>  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.158.248:80,192.168.218.93:80,192.168.79.54:80
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

I can see http://hostname-v1.local:8080

[image]

I can even log in to one of the pod and see that the container is correctly running my app

```
kubectl exec -it my-app-898f57d6f-dsfg6 /bin/bash
```

```
root@my-app-898f57d6f-dsfg6:/usr/src/app# curl localhost

Hello World !!
```

But

http://hostname-v1.local

shows

SERVICE UNAVAILABLE

**Question**:

Why is that I can not see my simple app running on:

http://hostname-v1.local (34.195.130.205 )

even though it is running inside the container?

BR

Comment: please share `kubectl get ep` ? thanks

Comment: ```                                                                                                                             
 NAME          ENDPOINTS                               AGE
hostname-v2   <none>                                  20h
kubernetes    192.168.219.41:443,192.168.94.137:443   27h
my-app        <none>                                  19h ```

Comment: `hostname-v2` service has no endpoints. `my-app` has no endpoints either. Ensure that `selector` for either or both of these services selects your application pod. And when one of these services has that pod as its endpoint, use it as service name for the Ingress resource.

Comment: Also current Ingress resource points to `hostname-v1` which doesn't exist.

Comment: It is IP 34.195.130.205 in /etc/hosts

Comment: @MasterOfTheHouse I have no idea what you're doing updating hosts file manually but it is something that you almost never have to do when configuring Ingress.

Comment: Can you post service definition YAML as well along with Pod YAML?

Comment: Just added service.yaml and deployment.yaml

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217705/discussion-between-masterofthehouse-and-ashu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your service selector is incorrect and hence, the pod isn't added as its endpoint. Selector has to be a set of labels that are present on the pods that you want to select for this service.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

In your Ingress definition, you're using `hostname-v1` as the backend service which doesn't seem to exist anywhere. Use `my-app` service instead.

```yaml
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hostname-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: hostname-v1.local
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: my-app
          servicePort: 80
```

Comment: This did not solve the issue. There should be still another problem

Comment: @MasterOfTheHouse could you find the Role/ClusterRole config (YAML) that you deployed while installing Traefik?

Comment: Also if you have the latest `kubectl describe svc my-app` output in the question, your selector is still incorrect. It needs to be `app=my-app`

Comment: I fixed and now it shows app=run.I updated the question

Comment: What's the error that you're getting now? Also does any backend show up on Traefik dashboard?

Comment: I visited the the public IP you have put in your question. The page seems to display a 404 which means the error is isolated in Ingress configuration now. First, you should try to use a wildcard host to test if Ingress controller is configured properly. If that doesn't work, your ingress controller most likely doesn't have permissions to access ingress resources in another namespace. Without seeing the Traefik YAML, its hard to tell.

Comment: This is how I applied the traefik manifest and at the same time we changed the LB type from NodePort to LoadBalancer

```bash
kubectl apply -f <(curl -so - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/v1.7/examples/k8s/traefik-deployment.yaml | sed -e 's/NodePort/LoadBalancer/')
```

Comment: @MasterOfTheHouse You also need to deploy RBAC config so that Traefik is able to access Kubernetes API server to find Ingress resources.
`kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/containous/traefik/v1.7/examples/k8s/traefik-rbac.yaml`

Comment: Yes I did that as well

Comment: @MasterOfTheHouse can you try it without the `host: hostname-v1.local` specified?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217747/discussion-between-masterofthehouse-and-ashu).

Comment: @MasterOfTheHouse try removing the hostname declaration from the Ingress resource and deploy it